# How to identify file path in error messages in Php?

Tags: php, regex

I want to identify text containing file paths. For the text below

> Typed property App\Http\Requests\ModuleRequest::$name must not be
> accessed before initialization

I should be able to detect the phrase `App\Http\Requests\ModuleRequest` from the message so that these can be treated differently. I'm using the following regular expression.

```
$expression = "/((\w)*[\\]\w+)*/";
$isFound = preg_match($expression, $message)
```

but it always return false. I checked the same on [https://regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) and it detects the pattern but my code is unable to do that. How can I find this pattern in the message. I'm using Php 8.2

Comment: Your expression works fine for me, provided you properly escape the forward slashes. However, your expression has a lot of unnecessary characters and can be simplified a bit, which may also make it easier to diagnose the issue. Try something like `(\w*\\\w+)*` instead.

Comment: but it also matches this *"project 65 not found"*

Comment: Could you clarify? That string is not mentioned anywhere in your question.

Comment: it needs to process all the error messages produced by the system and identify any that contains a file path, it does not make sense to write all the error messages here in the question

Comment: Right, and the regex I provided does that. I'm not suggesting that you include all of the error messages, but you do need to include enough information to reasonably be able to answer your question. Otherwise, we're all just taking shots in the dark. I can't write an expression for something I can't see.

Comment: Just `\w\\\w` will identify 2 word characters with a backslash in between, if you are using preg_match. See https://regex101.com/r/84l3UZ/1 Should the format of the file path in your case be more specific than that?

Comment: To figure a literal backslash in a regex pattern you need to escape it, but in addition, to figure a backslash in a PHP string, you need to escape it to: so you need 4 backslashes to figure one in a pattern in a php string, see: https://3v4l.org/HZQNb#v8.2.11

Answer (score 1):

Just my 2 cents.

You will have to escape the `\` properly since it is a regex meta-character. That being said, you will also need to use `preg_match_all` to get all the related file paths instead of stopping on just one.

```
/\w+\\\(\w+\\\?)+/
```

As you might have anticipated, the first `\w+` is used to get the start of the match followed by a `\` and then the remaining collection of words following the same pattern with an optional `\` repeated multiple times over.

```
<?php

 $test = 'Typed property App\Http\Requests\ModuleRequest::$name must not be accessed before initialization';

 if(preg_match_all('/\w+\\\(\w+\\\?)+/', $test, $matches) !== false){
        print_r($matches[0]);
 }
```

[**Online Demo**](https://3v4l.org/fpCMQ)

Comment: does it make a difference if I'm using Laravel 10? it doesn't match at all.

Comment: @SimpleFellow Regex has nothing to do with a framework. Can you show an example where it doesn't match?

Comment: for 24 hours only. I'm using free account: https://codeshare.io/mpWez4

Comment: also I'm using Phpstorm 2023.3 (student version)

Comment: @SimpleFellow Can you show a minimum reproducible example of the code where you used my regex and it didn't work? Any sample string where the path doesn't get captured? The code you showed right now has a lot of irrelevant information.